# Python to get path of folder that endswith today's date

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, directory, subprocess, ends-with

There are a lot of subdirectories in a directory. Every Subdirectory name ends  with a date. I want to to open a subdirectory that ends with today's Date.

Here is my code so far. But it is not Working.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
currentdate = now.strftime("%d")
currentmonth = now.strftime("%B")
print(currentdate)
print(currentmonth)


path = 'C:\\Users\\Mondoc\\Desktop\\SweetMemories'

for folder in path:
    if folder.endswith(currentdate):
        pathtofolder = folder
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('C:\\Users\\Mondoc\\Desktop\\SweetMemories'+pathtofolder)
```

My code is not working

Comment: Hint: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a great tool when dealing with paths and filenames in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating a string actually. Is this what you want?

```py
import os

# for folder in path:
#    if folder.endswith(currentdate):
for name in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(name) and name.endswith(...):
        ...
```

Comment: Not Working. It is taking recently created Folder. 
Let's say today's date is 6th.
i have folders:- jun3, jun8, jun6, jun10, feb.
Feb is the recently created folder. it is taking the recently created folder

Comment: It is also taking recently renamed folder